# SQL statement only select items that appear less than twice

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am currently working on a database which stores information which allows users to make reservations at a restaurant.

I am trying create a SQL statement which returns the times which appear less than twice in the reservations table.

At the moment I have this but this only returns the times which do not appear in the reservations table at all.

```
SELECT *
FROM TIME
WHERE
    TIME NOT IN (
        SELECT reservation.a_time
        FROM 
            RESERVATION
        JOIN TIME ON 
            reservation.a_time = time.time
        WHERE
            reservation.a_date = :the_date
    )
ORDER BY time;
```

The above statement returns all times which are not in the reservations table. However how would I return all times which appear in the reservations table including those that appear once but not those that appear twice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
  *
from
  TIME t
where
  (select 
    count(r.a_time) 
  from 
    RESERVATION r 
  where
    r.a_time = t.time and
    r.a_date = :the_date) < 2
```

or

```
select
  t.time /* and maybe other field, which you need to add to Group By as well */
from
  TIME t
  left join RESERVATION r on r.a_time = t.time and r.a_date = :the_date
group by
  t.time
having
  count(t.time) < 2
```

I prefer the first, because it is cleaner, more clear and can be expanded easier, despite the subselect.

Answer (score -1):

If the only thing you care about is returning `reservation.a_time`s that appear EXACTLY once, then this will do it:

```
SELECT reservation.a_time
FROM RESERVATION
GROUP BY reservation.a_time
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

This will group all `RESERVATION` entries by time, and only return the groups with exactly one member.

Comment: This won't return times that have no reservation at all.

Comment: @GolezTrol Then his question is worded strangely, because he specifically requests `all times which appear in the reservations table`.